# How to disable all unity shortcut keys when using Blender?

Tags: unity, 14.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, blender

I use Blender, and there are some key shortcuts that conflict with Unity 7, like Ctrl+Alt+NumPad0, disabled in the "shortcuts" menu (and sometimes, the shortcut is automaticaly (?) reactivated!). But there are other shortcuts which I don't know how to disable, like Alt+RightClick.

Does anyone know how to disable them all just when I use Blender.

thank you!

P.S.: I use Ubuntu 14.04 (no more 13.10)

In fact, the problem is that Blender and Unity shortcuts interfere, unlike with the KDE desktop, but I don't want to install KDE just for Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the keyboard shortcuts in blender can be customised. All editable shortcuts are listed in the [user preferences under input](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Preferences/Input).

The menu next to the search field allows you to search by name or key-binding. For Alt+RightClick search for mouse in keybinding. I doubt any mouse clicks will conflict though as they are clicks in the blender window for it to respond.

You can export the keyboard setup so that you can re-import it later or by saving user settings the same setup will be active each time you start blender.

Comment: ok, thank you! Nevertheless is there really no way to disable Unity's shortcuts? (I'd like to keep the default shortcuts for Blender) If not, no problem! But just for Knowledge :) P.S.: In fact, with Alt+RightClick, Unity reacts like with a right click on the menu bar.